# Spork-rails, rails 3.2 and 'no such file to load'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, spork

I'm having trouble with Rails 3.2 + Spork. When I run `bundle exec spork` I get the error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails-3.2.1/bin/spork:19:in `load': no such file to load -- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails-3.2.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc2/bin/spork (LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails-3.2.1/bin/spork:19:in `<main>'
```

As you might have noticed, I'm using RVM to manage my gems. Several times, I've tried reinstalling all my gems in a new gemset. I haven't had any luck. Has anyone else run into this?

I've created a Gist for of my Gemfile:
https://gist.github.com/1921929

Gist for my bundle:
https://gist.github.com/1925661

Comment: What testing framework do you use?

Comment: would be helpful if you include gists of `bundle install` and `gem list`

Comment: I've added a link the output for a `bundle update`. Because I am new to SO, I can only include two links in my description. Here's a link to te gist for my gemfile.lock
https://gist.github.com/1925690

Comment: maybe it was an error in installation of spork? try: `gem install spork --version 1.0.0rc2`

Comment: I've installed and uninstalled it several times. Each time I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out. It was permissions related. Running `bundle exec spork` would give me the error that's seen above. It had occurred to me that I might need to run it as `sudo bundle exec spork` and when I did I received a different error.

I just ran the command as rvmsudo or `rvmsudo bundle exec spork`, since I'm using RVM, and it worked just fine. It turns out that this had nothing to do with Spork having any issues. Thanks everyone for taking a look.

Comment: that's weird, in no way rvmsudo should be required, I can think of two issues - in first place you should not install rvm with sudo/as root, and second you need to add your user to rvm group and relogin

Comment: I had the same error message related to Spork, but I'm not using rvm. Running 'sudo bundle exec spork --bootstrap' worked for me, without a 'no such file to load error'. I guess a problem with executing the gem binary in /usr/local.

Comment: See issues [176](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/issues/176) and [180](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/issues/180) on the Spork project. There are open issues with the Spork file permissions.